# Can I batch data enter contributions using contact id instead of name?

Tags: civicontribute, profile, batches

I'd like to be able to batch enter contributions using the contact ID (or some other non-identifying information) rather than the contact name.

My workflow is this:
1. Treasurer of our church counts the offering and tithes and enters the info on a spreadsheet that is then given to the church secretary to enter into civi.
2. The church secretary shouldn't be privy to who is giving what to the church.

Was hoping that the batch data entry profile could be edited to remove the contact name and instead use the contact id but it doesn't look like it can without some custom coding.

Is there a workaround or alternative solution that doesn't require custom coding?

Answer (score 1):

Without coding? hmmm.

CSV importing might work.
Contributions -> Import Contributions

The CSV can work with the internal ID

You would not have a nice screen with the batch import but only work with Spreadsheet/CSV's and import those.

But.. person responsible for either importing the CSV or doing the batch entry should be able to check if it makes sense what he did. Otherwise you could end up with very strange data due to a small mistake. So my advise is for you to also check your permission policy. Maybe someone else entering the info or give that permission to the church secretary anyway.

Comment: I know about the CSV import. Would rather not do that as you say there's too much room for error. What would be perfect is if we could edit the bath data entry profile and remove the contact name and add contact ID.

Comment: well, there are more then one option, but they would involve coding.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the workflow?  ie have the treasurer enter the data to Civi?  That avoids the secretary being involved with the giving data.

Comment: at this time no.